# Why is pd.to_datetime() only changing type if utc is True?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After loading my csv file into my notebook in VS Code i wanted to change the columns type from `object` to `datetime` for some columns. So i did the following:

### object values of columns

These are example values in the columns.

```
my_col_1 -> 2022-02-07 20:19:04+01:00
my_col_2 -> 2020-10-27
my_col_3 -> 2020-10-27 16:00:00+01:00
my_col_4 -> 2020-10-27 18:00:00+01:00
```

### check

```
df_example.dtypes

my_col_1 object
my_col_2 object
my_col_3 object
my_col_4 object
```

### convert

```
format_1 = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' 
format_2 = '%Y-%m-%d' 

df_example['my_col_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_1'], format=format_1, 
    exact=True, errors='raise', utc=False)

df_example['my_col_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_2'], format=format_2,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=False)
    
df_example['my_col_3'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_3'],format=format_1,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=False)
    
df_example['my_col_4'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_4'],format=format_1,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=False)
```

### check

After converting the columns i wanted to check if everything worked out fine.

```
df_example.dtypes

my_col_1 datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
my_col_2 datetime64[ns]
my_col_3 object
my_col_4 object
```

This is strange. It seems `my_col_3` and `my_col_4` were not converted. But at the same time no Issue or Error was raised also while processing the code. `my_col_3` and `my_col_4` have the exact same format as `my_col_1`, yet they were not converted.

### second approach

lets change the `utc=False`to `utc=True`

```
df_example['my_col_3'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_3'],format=format_1,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=True)
    
df_example['my_col_4'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_4'],format=format_1,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=True)
```

### check

lets check again.

```
df_example.dtypes

my_col_1 datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
my_col_2 datetime64[ns]
my_col_3 datetime64[ns, UTC]
my_col_4 datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

now i have

- `my_col_1` with `UTC+01:00`
- `my_col_3` with `UTC+00:00` (turns `15:00:00` to `14:00:00` for example)
- `my_col_4` with `UTC+00:00` (the same)

### Question

This is strange. I do not want `my_col_3` and `my_col_4` to convert to the  `UTC+00:00` Timezone because i live in `UTC+01:00`.

Do i have to introduce another process step and re-apply my Timezone once again to these columns? But it seems redundant. Why not simply use the timezone already given in the columns like pandas does in `my_col_1`? Can i tell `pd.to_datetime()` what my timezone is? like `utc=True`but with `tz=01:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my Solution. Converting it with `dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')` does the job. So i guess there is no way around to just take the already given `+01:00` value. Turn the Column with `to_datetime` to UTC `+00:00`and afterwards you have to convert it to your Timezone again.

```
df_example['my_col_3'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_3'],format=format_1,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
    
df_example['my_col_4'] = pd.to_datetime(df_example['my_col_4'],format=format_1,
        exact=True, errors='raise', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
```

now my columns have changed into datetime with right Timezone

```
df_example.dtypes

my_col_3 datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
my_col_4 datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```